# Tikz: axis overlays markers

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am creating a simple graph having plots with markings. I use the decorations.markings library to create markers with a uniform distance between them. However, the markers close to the borders of the graph are overlaid by the axes, see the example below - markers on the right close to 1. I would prefer to place the markers "above" the axes and visualize them completely. Any idea how to do that? Thx for any advice/hint!

```
\documentclass[]{minimal}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,
  shapes.geometric,
  decorations.pathreplacing,
  decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
  matrix,shapes.symbols,automata,decorations.markings}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  nomorepostactions/.code={\let\tikz@postactions=\pgfutil@empty},
  mymark/.style 2 args={decoration={markings,
    mark= between positions 0.05 and 1 step
     (1/11)*\pgfdecoratedpathlength with{%
     \tikzset{#2,every mark}\tikz@options
       \pgfuseplotmark{#1}%
     },  
    },
  postaction={decorate},
  /pgfplots/legend image post style={
        mark=#1,#2,every path/.append style={nomorepostactions}
},
},
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=9cm, 
      width=13cm, 
      grid=major, 
      xmin=0, 
      xmax=1, 
      ymin=0, 
      ymax=1
     ] 

\addplot [color=black, 
      line width=1pt, 
      mark size=3pt, 
      mymark={*}{mark options={draw=white,fill=black}}
     ] coordinates {
              (0,   0)
              (0.99,0.5)
              (1,   1)
            };

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `clip=false` to the `axis` options:

> [image: Result]

Comment: I can't distinguish any difference between this and what the original poster has in the question.

Comment: @PaulStiverson Look around coordinates (1, 0.6) to (1, 1).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek : Excellent, thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, I see it now.